# Slidetoggle with a close button - jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm using the slidetoggle function to open & close a box when clicking on a link. I want to be able to add a "close" button (link) inside that box aswell as being able to close it via the slidetoggle trigger. How would i do this?

This is my jQuery:

```
$(".popup-b").hide(); 
$(".popup-l").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(0);
    return false;
});
```

My HTML

```
<a class="popup-l" href="#">Areas</a>
<div id="area-p" class="popup-box">
    <div class="close-this"><a href="#">Close</a></div>
    <p>This is the popup box</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/65wSn/1/) to see it working.

```
$(".popup-content").hide(); 
$(".popup-title").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(0);
    return false;
});
$(".popup-content .close-this").click(function(){
    $(".popup-title", $(this).parents(".popup-box")).click();
    return false;
});
```

This way the `active` class will be setted when the close link is used too.

You can also have many `.popup-box` on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(".popup-b").hide(); 
$(".popup-l").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(0);
    return false;
});
$(".close-popup").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(0);
);
```

HTML

```
<a class="popup-l" href="#">Areas</a>
<div id="area-p" class="popup-box">
    <div class="close-this"><a href="#" class="close-popup">Close</a></div>
    <p>This is the popup box</p>
</div>
```