# Slidetoggle Box one at a time

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using this piece of code on jsfiddle (
http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/65wSn/1/) which was posted in a previous question by me here: [Slidetoggle with a close button - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912286/slidetoggle-with-a-close-button-jquery)

My question is how can i adjust the jquery so that only one box is shown at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you like this solution? [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RmVyp/)

**EDIT:**

ups! we forgot to add: IF a popup is opened do not trigger any click functions! 'cause it's annoiyng! ;)

here is the new [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/RmVyp/1/)! (sorry for not fixing this in v0.01  ;D )

Comment: Perfect, Exactly what i was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide them all when the button is clicked and then turn toggle the active one directly after they're all hidden.

Comment: Hi, i tried this which did work but it disabled the "close" button and the toggle effect. Basically 1 box is always open. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/vyt92/1/